# ¿Cómo implementar una Cola en C?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una práctica de una Cola en Lenguaje C y mi código compila pero al ejecutarlo se crashea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Element
{
    struct Element *next; //Proximo elemento
    int dato;//Nombre del elemento
}Element;

Element *first=NULL; //primer elemento
Element *last=NULL; // ultimo elemento

//Crear el elemento
void createElement(Element *_Element, int dato )
{   
    //Se le asigna un dato al nuevo elemento
    _Element->dato=dato;
}

void push(Element *_Element)
{
    _Element->next=NULL;
    //Si el primero no existe quiere decir que no hay nada en la cola y esta vacia
    if(first==NULL){
        first=_Element; //El primer elemento será el nuevo elemento creado
        last=_Element; //Y también será el ultimo dado que solo existe uno en la cola
    }
    else{
        //Si no 
        last->next=_Element; 
        last=_Element;
    }
}

Element * pop()
{
    if(first==NULL)
        return NULL;
    //Decimos que el primer elemento en la cola es el que se va a devolver para imprimir
    Element * _Element_Return=first;
    //Y ahora el primer elemento es elemento proximo en la cola
    first=first->next;

    return _Element_Return;
}

//Desencolar e imprimir
void printAndPop()
{
    //Obtiene el primer elemento de la cola
    Element *i=pop();
    //Mientras todavia haya elementos en cola que los imprima
    while(i)
    {
        printf("%i\n",i->dato);
        //Vuelvo a obtener el primer elemento
        i=pop();
    }
}

int main ()
{
    Element *_Element;

    createElement(_Element,1);
    //Encolar
    push(_Element);
    //Desconlar e imprimir
    printAndPop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Da algún mensaje de error cuando falla el programa?

Comment: en mi caso el .exe ha dejado de funcionar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Element *_Element;

createElement(_Element,1);
```

La primera línea crea un puntero, puntero que como no le has facilitado ningún valor apunta a una región de memoria aleatoria. En la segunda línea llamas a una función que ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
void createElement(Element *_Element, int dato )
{   
    //Se le asigna un dato al nuevo elemento
    _Element->dato=dato;
}
```

Es decir, estás usando el puntero como si apuntase a una región válida, lo cual no es cierto. Al no estar inicializado el puntero tu programa intentará escribir muy probablemente en una zona de memoria que no está asignada a tu aplicación y eso el sistema operativo no lo va a permitir (al menos uno moderno).

Si no estás por la labor de usar memoria dinámica puedes hacer que `_Element` no sea puntero:

```
Element _Element;

// Usamos el '&' porque la función requiere un puntero
createElement(&_Element,1);
```

Si prefieres usar `malloc` para reservar la memoria acuérdate de liberarla después.

Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta no me había dado cuenta.

Comment: Son despistes bastante comunes tanto en C como en C++. Es algo que pasa hasta en las mejores familias

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en cómo creas el `_Element`, estás especificando que es un puntero a un tipo `Element` pero no estás reservando la memoria para ese elemento. Eso hace que cuando intentes asignar el valor de `dato` en la función `CreateElement` el programa falle.

La solución es simple, en el `main()` define el elemento así para reservar su espacio en memoria:

```
Element *_Element = (Element *) malloc (sizeof(Element));
```

Y al final del programa deberías liberar el espacio en memoria usando `free`:

```
free(_Element);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, eres buena persona.